# Proof of fixed point existence/uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I would like some comments on how to tidy up this proof and/or if there are any glaring mistakes.

> Let $A$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n \geqslant 1$. Suppose $f: A \to A$ satisfies
>   $$ d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y), \hspace{3mm} \forall x,y \in A, \hspace{3mm} x \neq y $$
>   where $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric. Show that $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Note that $A$ is compact (Heine-Borel Theorem). Let $\epsilon = \delta$. Then, we have that $d(f(x),f(x)) < \epsilon$ when $d(x,y) < \delta$. So, $f$ is a continuous mapping. Define $\xi: A \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\xi(x) = d(x,f(x))$. Since $A$ is compact, then $\xi$ attains a minimum on $A$, say at $x_{0}$. If $x_{0}$ is a fixed point, i.e. $f(x_{0}) = x_{0}$, then
    $$\xi(f(x_{0})) = d(f(x_{0}),f^{2}(x_{0})) = d(x_{0},f(x_{0})) = \xi(x_{0}) = 0$$

Then, if $x_{0}$ is not a fixed point, i.e. $x_{0} \neq f(x_{0})$, then
$$ \xi(f(x_{0})) = d(f(x_{0}),f^{2}(x_{0})) < d(x_{0},f(x_{0})) = \xi(x_{0}) $$
contradicting the assumption that $x_{0}$ is a minimum (**what exactly is the contradiction here?**) Thus, $x_{0} = f(x_{0})$.

For uniqueness of $x_{0}$, assume $x_{0} \neq x_{1}$, then
$$ d(x_{0},f(x_{1})) = d(f(x_{0}), f(x_{1})) < d(x_{0},x_{1}) $$
implying $f(x_{1}) \neq x_{1}$.

> Show that $f$ may not have a fixed point without the assumption that $A$ is closed and bounded.

Take $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x) = x + \tan(x + \pi/2)$ on the open interval $A = (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Note that
$$   f(x) = x \implies \tan(x + \pi/2) = 0 $$
which has no solution on the open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Thus, $f$ has no fixed point on this open interval.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of minimality, $ \phi(x_{0}) \leq \phi(x) $ for all $x$. In particular this is the case for $x = f(x_{0})$. Hence, $\phi(x_{0}) \leq \phi(f(x_{0}))  = d(f(x_{0}), f(f(x_{0}))) < d(x_{0}, f(x_{0})) = \phi(x_{0})$ - a number cannot be stricly less than itself! Note we have used that $f(x_{0}) \neq x_{0}$ to invoke the hypothesis to get the strict inequality in our calculation above.